# Components of DTO are Entities or DTOs as well?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dto

I have question of terminology. Reffering to Fowler, DTO is "An object that carries data between processes in order to reduce the number of method calls." (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html). As I understand, the only way to reduce method calls is to unite them. So DTO is composite object, containing some entities.

For example, we have two simple entities CoinInfo and ProductInfo:

```
public class CoinInfo
{
    public int CoinId { get; set; }
    public int Denomination { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}


public class ProductInfo
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public ProductTypes ProductType { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

And we also have complex object SomeDto, uniting CoinInfo and ProductInfo.

```
public class SomeComplex
{
    public List<CoinInfo> UserWallet { get; set; }
    public List<ProductInfo> Products { get; set;}
}
```

So, ProductInfo and CoinInfo are "DTO"s also or just "entities"?

Answer (score 5):

Data Transfer Objects come into play when you cross a class, component or application boundary. You use DTOs to reduce coupling between classes, components or applications.

For example when building a service that is to be consumed by clients, you may want to introduce three components:

- Service: containing the business logic and perhaps some service hosting boilerplate (though you'd usually want that last bit in its own project).
- Client library: that applications can use to call methods in the service
- Data Transfer Objects: these are referenced by both service and client.

Now your client application that wishes to communicate with that service only has to reference the client library and the DTO library. What other types your service uses to do its magic is not interesting at all to the client, and should remain hidden.

Now the point of DTOs is that you use them to model your API. You decide what gets exposed from your service, and what this data looks like. You can choose for composition, aggregating smaller DTOs into a larger one, as you show.

What you have to keep in mind is to **not expose service innards through the DTOs**. You're using the word "entities", which makes me think you're trying to expose, for example, Entity Framework models, aggregated in a DTO. You should not do this. Doing that you're creating a "leaky abstraction", making it harder to both change the database (add or remove columns, replace your ORM, ...) and to alter the information returned by the service (add or remove properties, ...). Besides that, using Entity Framework models as DTOs introduces problems with mass assignment, lazy loading and circular references, all of which requires workarounds.

You can work around those potential problems using attributes to let either your ORM or your service serializer ignore those extraneous properties, but those still are workarounds. If you really need to expose DTOs that look a lot like your data models, then introduce mapping (for example using AutoMapper):

- Service.Data: containing "entities".
- Service: maps "entities" to DTOs and returns/accepts the latter.
- Client library: still only sees and needs to reference the DTOs.

In this scenario, your service's data layer and the models returned from your service are decoupled.

If all of this is not what you're concerned about, but just the nomenclature: yes, all three classes you show are DTOs.

Answer (score 2):

Since `CoinInfo` and `ProductInfo` would be also suitable to perform *CRUD* (i.e. *Create, Read, Update, Delete*) operations I would say that the associate root and its own associations are also DTOs.

When you ask about if these classes are *entities*, it depends on what you understand as *entity*. If you want to know if they're domain objects, they're not unless you use them in your domain, and after all this would defeat the purpose of using the DTO pattern.

DTO works best with [façades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), because they're not necessarily tied to the domain since they're just interfaces to simplify the domain or any other layer (it will depend on the [façade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) implementation). That is, a DTO should be the best choice to input and output data to and from façades.

In other words: you shouldn't output domain objects across physical boundaries, because a domain object might contain too many information that can be a waste of data transfer and also you might expose data that's *private* to the domain and shouldn't be known to consumers of the whole domain.

DTOs play their own role mapping just the required data to be exposed to layers on top of the actual domain. Also, sometimes domain objects contain useless data that can be serialized/deserialized and recover a valid state of the whole object (*they might have some association with data connections: think about Entity Framework or NHibernate proxies which are associated to a domain context or session respectively... it's just an example, there're many others*).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of DTO is that they serve a very similar role as 'parcelable' in Android (which also requires that member variables be parcelable (either native types or directly implement parcelable interface).

Parcelable is used when crossing process boarders (IPC) and DTO is a slightly more broad pattern. (for IPC, client/server comm. etc.) (so as to explain what 'parcelable is', and how DTO differs)

DTO looks to have the same hierarchical makeup , everything inside a DTO must be serialiazable (though it looks to not be required to impl. some specific interface as in the Android case) so I would say that all 3 are DTOs. just some more complex than others.

---

> it's worth mentioning that another advantage is to encapsulate the
>   serialization mechanism for transferring data over the wire. By
>   encapsulating the serialization like this, the DTOs keep this logic
>   out of the rest of the code

From your link

Parcelable -requires- you to include the serialization code within the class. Whereas DTO it is just a good practice(not required I don' think)

(sorry for so much android comparison, I hope the compare/contrast helps)

Comment: I don't like this answer as a C#/.NET one... Comparing Android design patterns with more generic design patterns like DTO adds no detail to this question...